# Creating sparklines using matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, sparklines

I am working on matplotlib and created some graphs like bar chart, bubble chart and others.

Can some one please explain with an example what is difference between line graph and sparkline graph and how to draw spark line graphs in python using matplotlib ?

for example with the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[5,7,2,6,2]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

the line graph generated is the following:[image]

But I couldn't get what is the difference between a line chart and a spark lien chart for the same data. Please help me understand

Comment: 1/ What is a spark line graph? 2/ What have you already tried yourself?

Comment: sparkline graphs are drawn without any axes particularly to plot variations from one point to other. for example, for the stock exchange data, the closing price of each day in last 1 week is an example for sparkline

Comment: Can you update your question with that comment, or better, provide a link to one or more sparkline graphs: this is really where a pictures says more than a 1000 words. (I can make a plot of stock exchange closing prices, and I would call it a graph, not a spark line, so your description/example doesn't really help.)

Comment: Also, people here really like to see you made an effort to try and implement this yourself. There is a [matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) that may help finding something similar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [sparkline graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparkline) is just a regular plot with all the axis removed. quite simple to do with `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create some random data
x = np.cumsum(np.random.rand(1000)-0.5)

# plot it
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,3))
plt.plot(x, color='k')
plt.plot(len(x)-1, x[-1], color='r', marker='o')

# remove all the axes
for k,v in ax.spines.items():
    v.set_visible(False)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])

#show it
plt.show()
```

Comment: If the number of values in x are less, say we have only 5 values instead of 1000, then  I found no much difference between a line graph and spark line graph. can you please let me know the difference

Comment: There is no difference. A sparkline graph *is* a line plot. Just without (visible) axes and in a very flat and wide shape.

Comment: if the length of list is very large, and there is lot of variation in each value of data, like if one value in the x is 5 and other is 10000 then the plot is not effective, in that case how can we show variation between the values when no scaling is available.

Answer (score 14):

A sparkline is the same as a line plot but without axes or coordinates. They can be used to show the "shape" of the data in a compact way.

You can cram several line plots in the same figure just by using [subplots](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot) and [changing properties](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.setp) of the resulting [`Axes`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html) for each subplot:

```
data = np.cumsum(np.random.rand(1000)-0.5)
data = data - np.mean(data)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(411) # nrows, ncols, plot_number, top sparkline
ax1.plot(data, 'b-')
ax1.axhline(c='grey', alpha=0.5)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(412, sharex=ax1) 
ax2.plot(data, 'g-')
ax2.axhline(c='grey', alpha=0.5)

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(413, sharex=ax1)
ax3.plot(data, 'y-')
ax3.axhline(c='grey', alpha=0.5)

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(414, sharex=ax1) # bottom sparkline
ax4.plot(data, 'r-')
ax4.axhline(c='grey', alpha=0.5)


for axes in [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]: # remove all borders
    plt.setp(axes.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
    plt.setp(axes.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
    plt.setp(axes.get_xticklines(), visible=False)
    plt.setp(axes.get_yticklines(), visible=False)
    plt.setp(axes.spines.values(), visible=False)


# bottom sparkline
plt.setp(ax4.get_xticklabels(), visible=True)
plt.setp(ax4.get_xticklines(), visible=True)
ax4.xaxis.tick_bottom() # but onlyt the lower x ticks not x ticks at the top

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sparklines]